# C# Advanced guessing game

Tags: c#, beginner

I'm learning C# and after watching the course and get the basics I decided to write a small project. It's a guessing game where a player can:

1. guess (of course): that will subtract his/her energy rest: that will
2. recovery his/her energy but take out some time take a hint: get a
3. hint about the current puzzle but it takes out some time dice roll:
4. get random a positive or a negative effect
   It does all the tasks it has to do, it's all about code review. I will be grateful for all suggestions for optimization of solutions/other solutions, good practices (writing, commenting on the code) and everything else that you think may help me in the future.

PS: As I wrote above, it's my first C# project. Before, I wrote some simple and small projects in other technologies/languages.

It contains: Main program, Hero class, Puzzle class

**Main program**

```
using System;

namespace GuessingGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start();
        }

        static void Start()
        {
            bool playerAreDumb = true;
            while (playerAreDumb == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("================================================");
                Console.WriteLine("Hello in Guessing Game");
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"s\" to start a new game");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("What do you want to do: ");
                string playerInput = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (playerInput)
                {
                    case "s":
                        playerAreDumb = false;
                        StartNewGame();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Well yea... try again ok?");
                        Console.WriteLine("...");
                        Console.WriteLine("...");
                        Console.WriteLine("...");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static void StartNewGame()
        {
            // Introduction
            Console.WriteLine("You started a new game");
            Console.WriteLine("...");
            Console.WriteLine("...");
            Console.WriteLine("...");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Hero! You forgot to wear your plot armor and some random snake bites you. You will die in 24 hours.");
            Console.WriteLine("Yea well that's all. Good luck!");

            bool gameOver = false;
            while (gameOver == false)
            {
                /*Game loop
                In the beginning, the player will see hero condition, then I'll show all of the activities that he/she can do.
                Depending on his/her input I'll start the method. On the end I'll check if he/she is still alive. If yes another loop will happen */
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("================================================");
                CheckHeroCondition();
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"s\" to try to solve the puzzle");
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"r\" to rest");
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"h\" to get a hint");
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"l\" to try your luck");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("What do you want to do: ");
                string playerInput = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (playerInput)
                {
                    case "s":
                        TryToSolvePuzzle();
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        Rest();
                        break;
                    case "h":
                        GetHint();
                        break;
                    case "l":
                        DiceRoll();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Well yea... try again ok?");
                        break;
                }
                // Everytime when energy or timeLeft is changed, Hero.alive can change. If that happens, the game is over and player loses
                if (Hero.Alive == false) { gameOver = true; }
                // If player solves a puzzle, whichPuzzle is incremented. If WhichPuzzle returns 4 it means that the player solved all of the puzzles
                if (Puzzle.WhichPuzzle == 4) { gameOver = true; }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static void CheckHeroCondition()
        {
            int heroEnergy = Hero.Energy;
            int heroTimeLeft = Hero.TimeLeft;
            int[] heroStatuesCounters = Hero.StatusesCounters;

            string messageFirstLine; // line for energy and timeLeft
            string messageSecondLine = ""; // line for statues counters

            messageFirstLine = "Hero energy: " + heroEnergy + "%, Hero time left: " + heroTimeLeft + " hours";

            string statusMessagePart = "";

            /* I'll skip i=0 because the first status counter is for AHA Moment and I use this counter only to 
               determine what I should do if AHA Moment happens again in DiceRoll */
            // heroStatuesCounters.Length-1 -> I'll use i to go through the entire array. The returned length will be greater than the last index
           for (int i = 1; i <= heroStatuesCounters.Length - 1; i++)
           {
               /* messageSecondLine should look like e.g. "Motivation (2), Dizzines (4)" 
                first I need to check if a status is active (counter is not equal to 0), than write down the name of the status and add its counter*/
            if (heroStatuesCounters[i] != 0)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            statusMessagePart = "Motivation";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            statusMessagePart = "Narcolepsy";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            statusMessagePart = "Effective antidote";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            statusMessagePart = "Slow moves";
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            statusMessagePart = "Dizziness";
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            statusMessagePart = "Exhaustion";
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            statusMessagePart = "Student syndrome";
                            break;
                    }
                    // I'll need to remove the comma after the last status
                    messageSecondLine = messageSecondLine + statusMessagePart + " (" + heroStatuesCounters[i] + "), ";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(messageFirstLine);
            // removing comma on the end of the message and showing second line of message (if variable is "" there are no active effects)
            if (messageSecondLine != "")
            {
                messageSecondLine = messageSecondLine.Substring(0, messageSecondLine.Length - 2); // -2 -> because I need to remove: ", "
                Console.WriteLine(messageSecondLine);
            }
        }

        static void TryToSolvePuzzle()
        {
            /* Statues that may effect that action
               Motivation - extra energy after guessing the puzzle
               Effective antidote - more time after guessing the puzzle
               Dizziness - failed guessing may return a modified result of valid chars */
            int[] statusesCounters = Hero.StatusesCounters;

            Console.Write("Your guess: ");
            string playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();

            /* Puzzle.CheckPlayerGuess returns counter of valid chars in player's guess.
             If method returns >= 0 it means that the player's guess is not the correct answer. 
             If method returns -1 it means that the player has given the correct answer. */
            int validCharsCounter;
            validCharsCounter = Puzzle.CheckPlayerGuess(playerGuess);

            if (validCharsCounter == -1)
            {
                PlayerSolvedPuzzle();
            }
            else
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();

                // Dizziness - failed guessing may return a modified result of valid chars
                // Dizziness counter is the sixth one
                if (statusesCounters[5] != 0)
                {
                    // 1+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                    int counterChange = rnd.Next(-1, 1 + 1); // number that will determine if and how the counter will be modified
                    validCharsCounter = validCharsCounter + counterChange;

                    // if validCharsCounter was equal to 0 before being modified, after modifying it may be equal to -1
                    if (validCharsCounter == -1) { validCharsCounter = 0; }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("It's not the correct answer. In your guess " + validCharsCounter + " chars were on the right place");

                // subtracting energy
                // -20+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                int lostEnergy = rnd.Next(-30, -20 + 1); // the amount of energy that the player will lose after that guess

                string messageLostEnergy = Convert.ToString(lostEnergy); // e.g. -25
                messageLostEnergy = messageLostEnergy.Substring(1); // I'll cut the "-"
                Console.WriteLine("You lost " + messageLostEnergy + "% energy after that guess");

                Hero.ChangeEnergy(lostEnergy);
            }

            // statuses counters change
            // Motivation counter is the second one
            if (statusesCounters[1] != 0) { statusesCounters[1]--; }
            // Effective antidote counter is the fourth one
            if (statusesCounters[3] != 0) { statusesCounters[3]--; }
            // Dizziness counter is the sixth one
            if (statusesCounters[5] != 0) { statusesCounters[5]--; }

        }

        static void PlayerSolvedPuzzle()
        {
            /*if player solves a puzzle, whichPuzzle is incremented. 
            If WhichPuzzle returns 4 it means that the player has solved all of the puzzles */
            if (Puzzle.WhichPuzzle != 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulation! You solved the puzzle!");
                Hero.PlayerSolvedPuzzle();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulation! You solved all of the puzzles!");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("For that achievement, the medic in your village has finally let you out from his basement and healed you.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("I think you should report him somewhere...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Anyway good job :3 I hope that you enjoyed it");
            }
        }

        static void Rest()
        {
            /* Statues that may effect that action
               Narcolepsy - chance that rest will not give you energy */
            /* While resting, the player can recover between 30 and 50 energy but he/she will lose 2 or 3 hours. 
            In addition, he/she has a 1% chance to sleep for 8 hours -> this may happen only if the player has more than 8 hours left
            First, I'll check if he/she has more than 8 hours left. If yes, I'll check if long nap will happen. 
            If no, I'll check amount of hours that player will lose. After that, I'll check the amount of energy that the player will recover*/
            int[] statusesCounters = Hero.StatusesCounters;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int chance;

            // 2+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
            chance = rnd.Next(1, 2 + 1); // chance == 1 -> player will not restore energy
            //Narcolepsy counter is the third one
            if (chance == 1 && statusesCounters[2] != 0) // chance needs to be equal to 1 and Narcolepsy needs to be active
            {
                Console.Write("Because of narcolepsy you don't feel better after trying to rest.");
            }
            else
            {
                // adding energy
                if (Hero.Energy >= 100)
                {
                    Console.Write("Well you're already full of the energy.");
                }
                else
                {
                    int recoveredEnergy;
                    // Exhaustion - resting will give only half energy
                    // Exhaustion counter is the seventh one
                    if (statusesCounters[6] != 0)
                    {
                        // 25+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                        recoveredEnergy = rnd.Next(15, 25 + 1); // the amount of energy that the player will recover after that rest 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // 50+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                        recoveredEnergy = rnd.Next(30, 50 + 1); // the amount of energy that the player will recover after that rest
                    }

                    // checking to see if the player should get more energy than possible (energy > 100 after Hero.ChangeEnergy)
                    int energy = Hero.Energy;
                    if (energy + recoveredEnergy > 100)
                    {
                        // e.g. the hero has 90 energy and recoveredEnergy = 20 -> 90 + 20 = 110 > 100 
                        recoveredEnergy = 100 - energy; // e.g. -> recoveredEnergy = 100 - 90 = 10
                    }

                    Hero.ChangeEnergy(recoveredEnergy);
                    Console.Write("You have rested and you restored " + recoveredEnergy + "% of the energy!");
                }
            }
            // substract time
            // 100+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
            chance = rnd.Next(1, 100 + 1); // chance == 1 -> long nap
            if (Hero.TimeLeft > 8 && chance == 1) // may happen only if the player has more than 8 hours and chance will be equal to 1
            {
                Hero.ChangeTimeLeft(-8);
                Console.Write(" But you fell asleep and slept for 8 hours. " +
                    "After that \"long nap\" you're not even sure in which solar system you're.");
            }
            else
            {
                int timeCost;
                // Student syndrome - resting and taking a hint will take the maximum possible amount of time
                // Student syndrome counter is the eighth one
                if (statusesCounters[7] != 0)
                {
                    timeCost = -3;
                }
                else
                {
                    // -2+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                    timeCost = rnd.Next(-3, -2 + 1); // number that will determine how much time will this action cost
                }

                // Slow moves - resting and taking a hint will take more time
                // Slow moves counter is the fifth one
                if (statusesCounters[4] != 0)
                {
                    // -1+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                    int extraTimeCost = rnd.Next(-3, -1 + 1);
                    timeCost = timeCost + extraTimeCost;
                }

                string messageTimeCost = Convert.ToString(timeCost); // e.g. -2
                messageTimeCost = messageTimeCost.Substring(1); // I'll cut the "-"
                Console.WriteLine(" But it costed you " + messageTimeCost + " hours.");

                Hero.ChangeTimeLeft(timeCost);
            }

            // statuses counters change
            //Narcolepsy counter is the third one
            if (statusesCounters[2] != 0) { statusesCounters[2]--; }
            // Slow moves counter is the fifth one
            if (statusesCounters[4] != 0) { statusesCounters[4]--; }
            // Exhaustion counter is the seventh one
            if (statusesCounters[6] != 0) { statusesCounters[6]--; }
            // Student syndrome counter is the eighth one
            if (statusesCounters[7] != 0) { statusesCounters[7]--; }
        }

        static void GetHint()
        {
            /* Statues that may effect that action
               Slow moves - rest and taking hint will take more time */
            /* Player can get up to 3 hints. In addition, he/she has a 10 % chance to get a secret hint.
             First, I'll check if he/she will get the secret hint or the usual hint. After, that he/she will lose some time.
             At the end, I'll check if he/she didn't already get all of the hints. */

            int[] statusesCounters = Hero.StatusesCounters;

            string hint = "";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            // 10+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
            int chance = rnd.Next(1, 10 + 1); // chance == 1 -> secret hint
            if (chance == 1)
            {
                hint = Puzzle.GiveSecretHint();
            }
            else
            {
                hint = Puzzle.GiveHint();
            }

            // checking if he/she didn't already get all of the hints.
            if (hint != "You already know everything that you need! Take a nap or something.")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(hint);

                int timeCost;
                // Student syndrome - resting and taking hint will take the maximum possible amount of time
                // Student syndrome counter is the eighth one
                if (statusesCounters[7] != 0)
                {
                    timeCost = -4;
                }
                else
                {
                    // -2+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                    timeCost = rnd.Next(-4, -1 + 1); // number that will determine how much time will this action cost
                }

                // Slow moves - resting and taking a hint will take more time
                // Slow moves counter is the fifth one
                if (statusesCounters[4] != 0)
                {
                    // -1+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                    int extraTimeCost = rnd.Next(-3, -1 + 1);
                    timeCost = timeCost + extraTimeCost;
                }

                string messageTimeCost = Convert.ToString(timeCost); // e.g. -2
                messageTimeCost = messageTimeCost.Substring(1); // I'll cut the "-"
                Console.WriteLine("That action costed you " + messageTimeCost + " hours.");
                Hero.ChangeTimeLeft(timeCost);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(hint);
                Rest();
            }
            // statuses counters change
            // Slow moves counter is the fifth one
            if (statusesCounters[4] != 0) { statusesCounters[4]--; }
        }

        static void DiceRoll()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            //6+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
            int dice = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);

            switch (dice)
            {
                case 1:
                    /* AHA Moment: The player will get a hint about answer's length. 
                     If the player already got this hint once he/she, will get the exact length */
                    // correctCounter1 -> 1 because it's the first case
                    int correctCounter1 = 0; // AHA Moment counter it's the first one
                    int ahaMomentCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter1];
                    if (ahaMomentCounter == 0)
                    {
                        /*I need a number between the puzzle answer length -2 and the puzzle answer length 
                        for example, if the answer is 5 chars long, then hint may be: (3,5), (4,6), (5,7)*/
                        int answerLength = Puzzle.GiveAnswerLength();
                        int substractedAnswerLength = answerLength - 2;
                        // if the answer has only 3 or 4 chars I don't want to show hint: 1-3 or 2-4
                        if (substractedAnswerLength < 3) { substractedAnswerLength = 3; }

                        // answerLength + 1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                        int setBeginning = rnd.Next(substractedAnswerLength, answerLength + 1);
                        int setEnd = setBeginning + 2;

                        Console.WriteLine("AHA Moment: The answer for the current puzzle has between " + setBeginning + " and " + setEnd + " chars");

                        Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter1, 1);
                    }
                    else if (ahaMomentCounter == 1)
                    {
                        int answerLength = Puzzle.GiveAnswerLength();
                        Console.WriteLine("AHA Moment: The answer for the current puzzle has " + answerLength + " chars");

                        Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter1, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Really? 1 on a dice roll this many times?");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Okay... I'll give you one more hour for that");
                        if (Hero.TimeLeft < 24)
                        {
                            Hero.ChangeTimeLeft(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("OHH FOR FUCK'S SAKE! Seriously you already have the maximum amount of time left...");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("You know what...");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("You die: A pebble fell on your head and killed you");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("...");
                            Console.WriteLine("...");
                            Console.WriteLine("...");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine(":c");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Nah, just joking. Keep playing :3");
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    /*Refreshment: The player will get 100 energy. If he/she already has 100 energy a positive or a negative effect will happen:
                     Motivation - if the player will solve a puzzle in the next few guesses he/she will have more energy at the beginning of the next puzzle
                     Narcolepsy - the chance that resting will not give the player energy*/
                    if (Hero.Energy < 100)
                    {
                        Hero.ChangeEnergy(100); // I can only add/substract energy so now I'm sure that the player will have 100 energy
                        Console.WriteLine("Refreshment: You're full of energy!");
                    }
                    else // hero has 100 energy or more, so I'll check if Motivation or Narcolepsy happens
                    {
                        // 2+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                        int refreshmentChance = rnd.Next(1, 2 + 1);
                        if (refreshmentChance == 1) // refreshmentChance == 1 -> Motivation
                        {
                            // Currently I have 4 puzzles (0-3). If the current puzzle is the last one, this status will not give the player anything
                            if (Puzzle.WhichPuzzle == 3)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You should get a bonus for the the next puzzle but it's the last one," +
                                    " so the only thing that I can do is wishing you luck!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // correctCounter2 -> 2 because it's the second case
                                int correctCounter2 = 1; // Motivation counter is the second one
                                Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter2, 2);
                                int motivationCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter2];
                                if (motivationCounter == 1)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Motivation: If you will solve the puzzle in the next" +
                                    " attempt you will get 150% energy at the beginning of the next puzzle.");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Motivation: If you will solve the puzzle in the next " + motivationCounter +
                                    " attempts you will get 150% energy at the beginning of the next puzzle.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else // refreshmentChance == 2 -> Narcolepsy
                        {
                            // correctCounter2 -> 2 because it's the second case
                            int correctCounter2 = 2; //Narcolepsy counter is the third one
                            Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter2, 1);
                            int narcolepsyCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter2];
                            if (narcolepsyCounter == 1)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Narcolepsy: Within the next rest there is a 50% chance that you will not get any energy.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Narcolepsy: Within the next " + narcolepsyCounter +
                                    " rests its a 50% chance that you will not get any energy.");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case 3:
                    /*Immune reaction: The player will get 24 hours. If he/she already has 24 hours, a positive or a negative effect will happen:
                     Effective antidote - if the player will solve a puzzle in the next few guesses he/she will have more time at the beginning of the next puzzle
                     Slow moves - resting and taking a hint will take more time*/
                    if (Hero.TimeLeft < 24)
                    {
                        Hero.ChangeTimeLeft(24); // I can only add/substract energy so now I'm sure that the player will have 24 hours left
                        Console.WriteLine("Immune reaction: You have 24 hours left again!");
                    }
                    else // hero has 24 hours or more so I'll check if Effective antidote or Slow moves happens
                    {
                        // 2+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
                        int immuneReactionChance = rnd.Next(1, 2 + 1);
                        if (immuneReactionChance == 1) // immuneReactionChance == 1 -> Effective antidote
                        {
                            // Currently I have 4 puzzles (0-3). If the current puzzle is the last one this status will not give the player anything
                            if (Puzzle.WhichPuzzle == 3)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You should get a bonus for the next puzzle, but it's the last one," +
                                    " so the only thing that I can do is wishing you luck!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // correctCounter3 -> 3 because it's the third case
                                int correctCounter3 = 3; // Effective antidote counter is the fourth one
                                Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter3, 2);
                                int effectiveAntidoteCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter3];
                                if (effectiveAntidoteCounter == 1)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Effective antidote: If you will solve the puzzle in the next" +
                                        " attempt you will have 36 hours at the beginning of the next puzzle.");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Effective antidote: If you will solve the puzzle in the next " + effectiveAntidoteCounter +
                                    " attempts you will have 36 hours at the beginning of the next puzzle.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else // immuneReactionChance == 2 -> Slow moves
                        {
                            // correctCounter3 -> 3 because it's the third case
                            int correctCounter3 = 4; // Slow moves counter is the fifth one
                            Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter3, 1);
                            int slowMovesCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter3];
                            if (slowMovesCounter == 1)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Slow moves: Within the next resting or taking a hint you will lose bettwen 1 and 3 more hours.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Slow moves: Within the next " + slowMovesCounter +
                                    " rests and taking hints you will lose bettwen 1 and 3 more hours.");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case 4:
                    // Dizziness - failed guessing may return a modified result of valid chars
                    // correctCounter4 -> 4 because it's the fourth case
                    int correctCounter4 = 5; // Dizziness counter is the sixth one
                    Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter4, 2);
                    int dzizzinessCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter4];
                    if (dzizzinessCounter == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Dizziness: Within the next guessing, you may get a hint about valid characters, modified by -1 or +1.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Dizziness: Within the next " + dzizzinessCounter +
                            " guesses, you may get a hint about valid characters, modified by -1 or +1.");
                    }

                    break;

                case 5:
                    // Exhaustion - resting will give only half energy
                    // correctCounter5 -> 5 because it the fifth case
                    int correctCounter5 = 6; // Exhaustion counter is the seventh one
                    Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter5, 2);
                    int exhaustionCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter5];
                    if (exhaustionCounter == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exhaustion: Within the next rest, you will recover only half of the energy.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exhaustion: Within the next " + exhaustionCounter +
                            " rests, you will recover only half of the energy.");
                    }

                    break;

                case 6:
                    /* Mobile games - The player will lose 6 hours. If he/she has less than 7 hours another status will happen
                    Student syndrome - resting and taking a hint will take the maximum possible amount of time */
                    if (Hero.TimeLeft > 6)
                    {
                        Hero.ChangeTimeLeft(-6);
                        Console.WriteLine("You played on your phone and lost 6 hours,");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("You have also run out of battery so you cannot use it now,");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Seriously, you could use it in many other good ways,");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("In the future, perhaps you should think twice before you do something like this.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // correctCounter6 -> 6 because it's the sixth case
                        int correctCounter6 = 7; // Student syndrome counter is the eighth one
                        Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters(correctCounter6, 2);
                        int studentSyndromeCounter = Hero.StatusesCounters[correctCounter6];
                        if (studentSyndromeCounter == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Student syndrome: The next rest or taking a hint will take the maximum possible amount of time.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Student syndrome: The next " + studentSyndromeCounter +
                                    " rests and taking hints will take the maximum possible amount of time.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Hero Class**

```
using System;

namespace GuessingGame
{
    static class Hero
    {
        private static int energy = 100; // hero have 100% energy at the beginning
        private static int timeLeft = 24; // hero have 24h time left at the beginning 
        private static int[] statusesCounters = // hero doesn't have any active status at the beginning
        {
            0, // AHA Moment - Player will get hint about answer's length
            0, // Motivation - extra energy after guessing the puzzle
            0, // Narcolepsy - chance that rest will not give you energy
            0, // Effective antidote - more time after guessing the puzzle
            0, // Slow moves - resting and taking hint will take more time
            0, // Dizziness - failed guessing may return a modified result of valid chars
            0, // Exhaustion - resting will give only half energy
            0  // Student syndrome - resting and taking hint will take the maximum possible amount of time 
        };
        private static bool alive = true; // the flag that changes if the player loses

        public static void ChangeTimeLeft(int timeChangeAmount)
        {
            timeLeft = timeLeft + timeChangeAmount;
            if (timeLeft >= 24) { timeLeft = 24; } //hero should not have more than 24 hours except for Effective antidote status
            if (timeLeft <= 0) { HeroDie("time"); } 
        }
        public static void ChangeEnergy(int energyChangAmount)
        {
            energy = energy + energyChangAmount;
            if (energy >= 100) { energy = 100; } //hero should not have more than 100 energy except for Motivation status
            if (energy <= 0) { HeroDie("energy"); }

        }
        
        public static void ChangeStatusesCounters(int whichStatus, int counterChangeAmount)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Question: can I block the passing of some parameters in the method? Just as the compiler will show an error 
                if it tries to enter int into a parameter that should be a string, is it possible to block the passing of an argument 
                of the appropriate type, but, for example, greater than X?*/
                statusesCounters[whichStatus] = statusesCounters[whichStatus] + counterChangeAmount;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WTF Hero.ChangeStatusesCounters: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void HeroDie(string reason) 
        {
            alive = false;
            if (reason == "time")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You die: The venom killed you :c");
            }
            else if (reason == "energy")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You die: You died of exhaustion :c");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Amm... to be honest I don't know why you're here");
                Console.WriteLine("Hmm... OK");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You die: A pebble fell on your head and it killed you");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("...");
                Console.WriteLine("...");
                Console.WriteLine("...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(":c");
            }
        }

        public static void PlayerSolvedPuzzle()
        {
            /* after solving a puzzle the player will not get extra energy (unless motivation status is active),
            but he/she will get more time*/
            if (statusesCounters[1] != 0) // second counter is Motivation counter
            {
                energy = 150;
                Console.WriteLine("After that success, you feel full of energy! You have 150% energy now.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("After solving that puzzle, an antidote appears in the room where you are. " +
                "It temporarily helps your body to fight the venom.");
            if (statusesCounters[3] != 0) // fourth counter is Effective antidote counter
            {
                timeLeft = 36;
                Console.WriteLine("That antidote was really effective. You have 36 hours instead of 24 hours to solve the next puzzle!");
            } else
            {
                if (TimeLeft < 24)
                {
                    timeLeft = 24;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have 24 hours to solve the next puzzle");
                }
            }

            // AHA Moment counter needs to be reset so player can get this again for the next puzzle
            statusesCounters[0] = 0;
        }

        public static int Energy
        {
            get { return energy; }
        }

        public static int TimeLeft
        {
            get { return timeLeft; }
        }

        public static int[] StatusesCounters
        {
            get { return statusesCounters; }
        }

        public static bool Alive
        {
            get { return alive; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Puzzle Class**

````
using System;

namespace GuessingGame
{
    static class Puzzle
    {
        private static string[] answers = { "egg", "sleeping", "cat", "addiction"};
        private static string[] secretHints = 
            {"Have you had breakfast today?",
            "Although many would like to hug Keanu Reeves, this puzzle is about hugging his friend handing out pills to people.",
            "Let's face it, Jerry was the bad guy.",
            "How often did your mom tell you that playing games are unhealthy for you?" };
        private static string[,] hints = {
            {"You need to break it before you can use it.", // hints for first puzzle
             "A container without hinges, lock or a key, yet a golden treasure lies inside.",
             "It is not unusual and yet philosophers were fascinated with the chronological relationship between this and its creator." },
            {"If someone asks you if you are doing this at this moment, you cannot answer truthfully.", // hints for second puzzle
             "It seems to shorten your life. However, if you gave it up, you would really shorten your life.",
             "You do it every day, but you never see yourself doing it."},
            {"You wanted to get rid of rodents, and now you get them as gifts.", // hints for third puzzle
             "Most people love it or hate it - rarely something in the middle.",
             "Why do you need an owl or a toad when you can have it?"},
            {"Pavlov could call it conditioning, but many will call it a different way.", // hints for fourth puzzle
             "It always starts innocently and often also enjoyable.",
             "Habits are good, unless you become their slave."} };
        private static int whichPuzzle = 0; // which puzzle is currently being solved
        private static int whichHint = 0; // which hint WILL be given

        public static string GiveHint()
        {
            /*If the player is given the same hint, he/she gets nothing -> After the last hint, instead of getting another one, 
              the player will rest*/
            if (whichHint <= 2)
            {
                whichHint++;
                if (whichHint == 3) // Player will get now the third and the last hint, so he/she should know that the next one will not be given
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It's the last hint. You'll not get another one!");
                }
                // 'whichHint - 1' because I need to increment the counter before return
                return "Your hint: " + hints[whichPuzzle, whichHint - 1]; 

            } else
            {
                return "You already know everything that you need! Take a nap or something.";
            }
        }

        public static string GiveSecretHint()
        {
            /*If the player is given the secret hint again, he/she gets nothing -> After getting it once, it will be replaced with an empty
            string and the usual hint will be given when the secret hint is drawn again*/
            if (secretHints[whichPuzzle] != "")
            { // first time
                string secretHint = "Wild secret hint appeared :O " + secretHints[whichPuzzle];
                secretHints[whichPuzzle] = "";
                return secretHint;
            } else
            { // not first time
                return GiveHint();
            }
        }

        public static int CheckPlayerGuess(string playerGuess)
        {
            /* first method checks if playerGuess is the correct answer
            yes -> player solved the puzzle
            no -> if the char on a specific position in the answer for the current puzzle, and the player's guess is the same, 
            validCharsCounter will be increment */
            /* if method return >= 0 it means that the player's guess is not the correct answer. 
             * If method return -1 it means that the player has given the correct answer */
            string currentAnswer = answers[whichPuzzle];

            if (currentAnswer == playerGuess)
            {
                whichPuzzle++;
                whichHint = 0;
                return -1;
            }

            int validCharsCounter = 0;
            // playerGuess.Length-1 -> I'll use i to go through the entire array. The returned length will be greater than the last index
            for (int i = 0; i <= playerGuess.Length-1; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (currentAnswer[i] == playerGuess[i]) { validCharsCounter++; }
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return validCharsCounter;
        }

        public static int GiveAnswerLength()
        {
            return answers[whichPuzzle].Length;
        }

        public static int WhichPuzzle
        {
            get { return whichPuzzle; }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: It may be easier for you in this way -> https://github.com/GravityCat190/Advanced-Guessing-Game

Comment: _bool playerAreDumb = true_ - never hath truer words been writ.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("================================================");` I rarely meet someone who knows that this line can be rewritten with pretty useful `string` constructor. Take it `Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 46));`

Comment: Nice game, try the typewriter feature `private static void TypeWrite(string s) { foreach (char c in s) { Console.Write(c.ToString()); if (!Console.KeyAvailable) Thread.Sleep(50); } if (Console.KeyAvailable) Console.ReadKey(true); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to C# :)

### The good parts

- In general, I like how you name your variables
- A lot of explanatory comments - it's good to explain why certain things are implemented the way they are. However, the necessity to write many comments points to possible improvements.

### Possible improvements

#### Encapsulate related stuff

You may notice that your methods are quite long and sometimes noisy. Also, quite some code under some of the `case` statements - e.g. [Program.cs line 412](https://github.com/GravityCat190/Advanced-Guessing-Game/blob/69265145b1d28fc6aae05fddf10797d2454c2957/GuessingGame/GuessingGame/Program.cs#L412).

You could start by identifying and grouping some chunks into separate methods, to **improve readability** - code is read way more often than written. For example, the user prompts:

```
Console.WriteLine("You started a new game");
Console.WriteLine("...");
Console.WriteLine("...");
Console.WriteLine("...");
```

This can be grouped into a new method `PromptNewGame()`

```
// new method
private void PromptNewGame()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You started a new game");
    Console.WriteLine("...");
    Console.WriteLine("...");
    Console.WriteLine("...");
}

// use it in program.cs
// ...
PromptNewGame();
// ...
```

As a next step, maybe you want to group all prompt-related code together in a separate class with many methods like this: `UserPrompts.PrintSomeInstructions()`. You do this already with some functionality (`Hero`, `Puzzle`), but not everywhere.

In general I would move most of the methods out of the `Program` class into a new `Game` class. That class can host the whole flow of the game - `StartNewGame()`, `TryToSolvePuzzle()` etc.

In `Program` you would then only call `Game.StartNewGame()`.

Another example:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
//6+1 -> Random.Next excludes maxValue (2 argument)
int dice = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);

// maybe put all of that into a separate method and call it like this - readability improved
int dice = RollTheDice();
```

#### See if you can get rid of "magic" integers and strings

You have many places like this - `case "s"`, `case 5:`, `statusesCounters[3]`, `Hero.Energy >= 100`. This makes your code less readable and can cause difficulties if you need to add/change some of these values.

There are multiple techniques to avoid this:

- one of the simplest ones - capture some of those numbers into `const`s

```
private const int MAX_ENERGY = 100;

// and use it everywhere in the code...
if (Hero.Energy >= MAX_ENERGY) ...
```

Here as well, you might discover that there are related constants and they may be grouped int a separate class, e.g. `GameParameters`. This will declutter the class where the logic using those constants is implemented.

- use `enum`s

One example could be HeroStatus (if I understand the game correctly :)):

```
public enum HeroState
{
    Motivation,
    Narcolepsy,
    SlowMoves,
    // and others...
}

// then you can use it in a Dictionary to track `statusesCounters`:
static class Hero
    {
        // other stuff... 
        private static Dictionary<HeroState, int> statusesCounters = new Dictionary<HeroState, int>()
        {
            { HeroState.Motivation, 0 },
            { HeroState.Narcolepsy, 0 },
            { HeroState.SlowMoves, 0 }
        }; // P.S. This can be even automated by iterating through the enum values

// then use it elsewhere without the need for extra comments
if (statusesCounters[HeroState.Motivation] != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

- use polymorphism (sub-classes) - this can be a bit more advanced, but feel free to google *"replace switch-case with polymorphism"*

#### Misc

- Make use of string interpolation

```
// this...
Console.WriteLine("That action costed you " + messageTimeCost + " hours.");

// ... can be replaced with this
 Console.WriteLine($"That action costed you {messageTimeCost} hours."); // notice the $ sign
```

- Take a look at the `foreach` statement. Often you won't need the `for` loops and the code will be easier to read

In general you can achieve a lot by doing these small incremental refactorings. Don't take it as a strict rule, but if you see that your method or class starts becoming a long one with hundreds of lines, you may want to look at encapsulating related code into separate methods/classes.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I checked "String interpolation" and it'll be super helpful so I'll use it for sure. I'll also look more about enums and Polymorphism. 
You have right about "magic" integers and strings -> the fact that I have to comment on it already shows that I should change it.

Comment: Great first review!

Comment: @GravityCat if you're fine with the review, you may mark the answer as accepted.